# Using Mongo Cache as a replacement for redis

Tags: mongodb, redis, wiredtiger

Currently, i am writing data into redis which is reduced to mongo every 2 minutes. I am wondering if i can use Mongo Cache instead of redis here. This will save the cost of 2 dbs in production.Also,the mongodb page says :

> The WiredTiger cache stores uncompressed data and provides in-memory-like performance

I want to test it but i am not able to find any documentation for playing around with WiredTiger Cache.

Note: Wiredtiger is default mongo storage engine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If you want to tune mongodb behavior have a look at mongodb performance tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Mongo DB as a replacement for Redis by specifying the In Memory storage engine:

```
mongod --storageEngine inMemory --dbpath <path>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/inmemory/).

I may be wrong, but I believe that you will still need to run 2 Mongo DB servers, one running in Wired Tiger for disk storage, and the other running with In Memory storage for your cache service.

Comment: I know about the In Memory storage engine. Using it will still mean 2 dbs in production (two storage engines). I am suggesting why can't we use WiredTiger cache instead of another storage engine?